# why is my object not staying in the same spot I told it to stay

Tags: python, pygame

So for some reason, my object/Rule is not staying in the same spot I told it to, every time I move, it will move the opposite direction I do and every time I collide with my platform's and press a or somthing, it will move right but if I'm colliding with a platform while pressing d it will move left. https://gyazo.com/b3adcbe08a79760e1cd0ded940ee2373 I want it to stay in the same spot but it is not staying in the spot.

I wrote this code but it is only working for my platform

```
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x -= playerman.speed
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x -= playerman.speed
        
 

    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x += playerman.speed
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x += playerman.speed
```

My full code

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((700,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Noobs First Game")


move = pygame.image.load("WASD.png")

# Playerman
class Player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.JumpCount = 10
        self.fall = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)
    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.get_rect())

class Platform:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y =y
        self. width = width
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 4
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def get_rect(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        return self.rect
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.get_rect())


class Rule:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y =y
        self. width = width
        self.color = color
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 4
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


# Colors for hitbox
white = (255,255,255)
green = (0,255,0)

# Drawing Player
playerman = Player(350,445,40,40,white)

#Drawing Platforms
platform1 = Platform(300,-9.1,40,500,green)
platform2 = Platform(330,451,2000,40,green)
platform3 = Platform(2300,-9.1,40,500,green)

# Drawing Rule
rule1 = Rule(350,-9.1,100,500,green)
rule2 = Rule(20000,-9,1,5,green)

# List
platforms = [platform1,platform2,platform3]

rules = [rule1,rule2]


# draws map
platformGroup = pygame.sprite.Group
Level = [
"                                             1",
"                                             1",
"                         1  1                1",
"                         1  1                1",
"                         11 1                1",
"                         1  1                1",
"                    1    1  1                1",
"           1   1   111   1 11                1",
"           1   1  11111     1              ",]

for iy,row in enumerate(Level):
    for ix, col in enumerate(row):
        if col == "1":
            new_platforms = Platform(ix*50,iy*50.2,50,50,(255,255,255))
            platforms.append(new_platforms)
    
            

# Windows color
def redrawwindow():
    window.fill((0,0,0))

    # Drawing the player and other stuff to the screen
    playerman.draw()

    for Platform in platforms:
        Platform.draw()
    for Rule in rules:
        Rule.draw()

x = 10
y = 10
x_change = 0
y_change = 0
old_x = x
old_y = y
fps = (30)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False



    if playerman.y < 250:
        playerman.y += 1
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.y += playerman.speed

    if playerman.y > 410:
        playerman.y -= playerman.fall
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.y -= playerman.fall


    
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            x_change = -7
        if event.key == pygame.K_a:
            x_change = 7

    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_a:
            x_change = 0

        x += x_change
        if x > 500 - playerman.width or x < 0:
            x = old_x
           
        # lets player move
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    px, py = playerman.x, playerman.y


    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x -= playerman.speed
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x -= playerman.speed
        
 

    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x += playerman.speed
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x += playerman.speed



    platform_rect_list = [p.rect for p in platforms]
    player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
    player_rect.topleft = (px, py)


    playerman.y = py
    if player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list) < 0:
        playerman.x = px
###########
    move_right = keys[pygame.K_d]
    move_left = keys[pygame.K_a]
    if move_right: 
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x -= Platform.speed
    if move_left:
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x += Platform.speed

    platform_rect_list = [p.get_rect() for p in platforms] # get_rect()
    player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
    player_rect.topleft = (px, py)

    playerman.y = py
    cI = player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list)
    if cI >= 0:
        # undo movement of platforms dependent on the direction and intersection distance
        playerman.x = px
        if move_right: 
            dx = platform_rect_list[cI].left - player_rect.right
            for Platform in platforms:
                Platform.x -= dx
                Platform.get_rect() # update rectangle
        if move_left:
            dx = platform_rect_list[cI].right - player_rect.left
            for Platform in platforms:
                Platform.x -= dx
                Platform.get_rect() # update rectangle

##############                
  
    # About isJump
    if not playerman.isJump:
        playerman.y += playerman.fall
        playerman.fall += 1
        playerman.isJump = False

        # this part lets you jump on platform only the top 
        collide = False
        for Platform in platforms:
            if playerman.get_rect().colliderect(Platform.rect):
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.y = Platform.rect.top - playerman.height
                if playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.left and playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.left - playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.left - playerman.width
                if playerman.rect.left < Platform.rect.right and playerman.rect.right > Platform.rect.right + playerman.width:
                    playerman.x = Platform.rect.right
                       
            # colliding with floor      
            if playerman.rect.bottom >= 500:
                collide = True
                playerman.isJump = False
                playerman.Jumpcount = 10
                playerman.y = 500 - playerman.height

        # Jumping
        if collide:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                playerman.isJump = True
                py -= playerman.speed
            playerman.fall = 0

    # Jump Count

    else:
        if playerman.JumpCount >= 0:
            playerman.y -= (playerman.JumpCount*abs(playerman.JumpCount))*0.3
            playerman.JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            playerman.isJump = False
            playerman.JumpCount = 10

    redrawwindow()
    
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: This is one the best titles lol, now object, stay stayyy I SAID STAY

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't think of any other title's while making this. XD

Comment: Don't apologise, its amazing

Comment: okay then i wont XD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must move the `Rule` object like the `Platform` objects. If the player hits a platform, you have to "undo" the movement of the `Rule` object as you do it for the `Platform` objects:

```py
while run:
    # [...]

    # lets player move
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    px, py = playerman.x, playerman.y

    platform_rect_list = [p.rect for p in platforms]
    player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
    player_rect.topleft = (px, py)

    playerman.y = py
    if player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list) < 0:
        playerman.x = px

    move_right = keys[pygame.K_d]
    move_left = keys[pygame.K_a]
    if move_right: 
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x -= playerman.speed
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x -= playerman.speed     # <---
    if move_left:
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x += playerman.speed
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x += playerman.speed     # <---

    platform_rect_list = [p.get_rect() for p in platforms] # get_rect()
    player_rect = playerman.get_rect()
    player_rect.topleft = (px, py)

    playerman.y = py
    cI = player_rect.collidelist(platform_rect_list)
    if cI >= 0:
        # undo movement of platforms dependent on the direction and intersection distance
        dx = 0
        if move_right: 
            dx = platform_rect_list[cI].left - player_rect.right
        if move_left:
            dx = platform_rect_list[cI].right - player_rect.left
        for Platform in platforms:
            Platform.x -= dx
            Platform.get_rect() # update rectangle
        for Rule in rules:
            Rule.x -= dx             # <---
```